# Add class to out of stock variant

Tags: shopware

I need to add a CSS class to a variant which is out of stock, that way I would know, before hand, which variant has or has not stock available.

I have been checking the detail page **(specifically the buy_container.tpl file)** to see if there's a clue in there. I used var dump to check the **$sArticle.sConfigurator** but it doesn't say if one of the variants is out of stock. I also checked the **$sArticle.instock** and **$sArticle.isAvailable** but as the detail page uses ajax to reload the data, those variables only work after selecting the out of stock variant, and I need to know which variant is out of stock before hand.

This is where I need to add the CSS class:

```
{foreach $sConfigurator.values as $configValue}

   {if !{config name=hideNoInstock} || ({config name=hideNoInstock} && $configValue.selectable)}

     <div class="variant--option {if $outofstock}OUT-OF-STOCK{/if} {if $configValue.selected}variant-selected{/if}">

        <input type="radio"
          class="option--input"
          {if $configValue.selected} checked="checked"{/if}
          value="{$configValue.optionID}"
          name="group[{$sConfigurator.groupID}]"

          {if $theme.ajaxVariantSwitch} 
          data-ajax-select-variants="true"{else} 
          data-auto-submit="true"{/if} />
          {$configValue.optionname}{if $configValue.upprice} {if $configValue.upprice > 0}{/if}{/if}

     </div>
  {/if}

{/foreach}
```

Any clue would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the selection-configurator. With this configurator this information will be available. See: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.5/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/detail/config_variant.tpl#L31

[image]

No other configurator will provide this data. When you want to use an other configurator, you need to implement such a variable/function yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need to use another configurator, so as you said, I'm gonna have to implement that variable by myself, any idea how to do that? Do I have to override the controller for that page?

Comment: I think I found the solution, not sure if it's correct but it's helping me to do what I need. In the tpl file which loads the configurator variants, like the one in the link you posted above, there's a variable named $configValue.selectable, not sure why they named it that way but looks like it returns false when a variant is out of stock.